# Html is not showing, just when I reload

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angularjs and I'm trying to use bootstrap-select.
But when I enter in the url that is using the bootstrap-select doesn't appear. Just when I refresh the page.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 label-center">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': form.mapping.$invalid && submitted}">
        <label>{{'Mapping' | translate}}</label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="mapping" ng-model="workflowList[0]">
            <option>Nothing Selected</option>
            <option ng-repeat="w in workflows[0]" ng-value="w.resource_uri">{{w.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you pressed `F12` are there any errors in the console before the refresh?

Comment: There is no error..

Comment: Edit your question and post your config code, what url you are putting, and the full html where the select is located..

Comment: a working example would be nice

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't letting me put my code.. I think is something about the code is not write..

Comment: It is better if you use angular bootstrap rather than plain bootstrap.